# how to show JBG (yes, it is JBG) on web page

Tags: image, servlets

Here we store image bytes in JBG (not JPG) format, how can I show the image in web page like use img tag.

I prefer to convert the bytes into jpg image stream in java backend, but I don't know how to convert.

Comment: well, certainly the browser won't render this format, so it seems to be just a matter of converting these JBIG files using some java library. Have you tried something like https://github.com/levigo/jbig2-imageio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some googling around (I am not a JBG or Java image processing expert) shows that there is a [JBIG Java image library](https://github.com/levigo/jbig2-imageio%20levigo/jbig2). It plugs into the [Java ImageIO framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html#package_description) which looks like has a JPEG plugin by default. You could use that.